# How do I convert Firebase Cloud Functions' timestamp format into something like 1665346052?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In my Firebase cloud functions, I am using `admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),` to write a server timestamp to Firestore. The format that this outputs is `October 5, 2022 at 10:42:09 PM UTC-5`. However, the problem is that when I write to Firestore from the client, I use `DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),` which outputs as `1665027682`. I don't want to use 2 different formats for my datetimes, so how do I convert the server timestamp in cloud functions to the unix format (to match the client's output)?

Comment: You can use [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp/) as `moment().unix();` or without any package, just `Math.floor((new Date).getTime()/1000);` to get same result in your cloud function. For setting up timezone, you can either provide the time zone or add/subtract time to adjust for your time zone as `moment().add(4, 'hours').unix();`, read the docs or visit the npm directory [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment).

Comment: @LalitFauzdar I used `Math.floor((new Date).getTime()/1000);` and it worked! Do you think this a reliable method of getting this date in the correct format in a production environment?

Comment: This is a reliable method and is provided by the native JS APIs, this is not a workaround. It is divided by 1000 and then rounded to nearby value using `Math.floor()`  because by default, it provides the value in milliseconds which is converted to seconds for your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Lalit Fauzdar you may use this code below to convert the server timestamp:

```
Math.floor((new Date).getTime()/1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a [`Timestamp` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) you can get the milliseconds-since-the-epoch value by calling [`toMillis()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#tomillis) on it. From its documentation:

> The point in time corresponding to this timestamp, represented as the number of milliseconds since Unix epoch 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.

Comment: Very good tip, but I'm iffy on having different date formats in different places (timestamp here and a string over there). I'm coming from SQL Server where everything is just a datetime, and for me that simplicity saves you so much unnecessary stress.